# Advantages / Interpretation of time series cross validation results ARIMA

Tags: time-series, cross-validation, arima

How to you evalute and interprete the results of time series cross validation.
I did an expanding window cross validation for my SARIMA model.

What advantage do I have for applying this corss vlaidation?
What conclusion can I draw from this cross validation?

The MAPE / RMSE is declining the longer the training set gets.

Do you train the model during cross validation with the same paramters SARIMA (1,1,1) x (0,1,1)12  or do you identify the order of parameters new after each iteration?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Your question is quite broad and would need a lengthy answer which could otherwise be found in some paper or textbook chapter on (time series) cross validation. Could you narrow it down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see three separate questions here:

1. **Why do a sliding window validation?**
   I like [this article](https://machinelearningmastery.com/backtest-machine-learning-models-time-series-forecasting/) which addresses splitting data for evaluation of time series models. To quickly summarize, sequential observations are correlated in time series. A normal train/test split which assumes independence of samples doesn't make sense. Sliding window validation (also referred to as a walk forward validation) allows you to test predictive performance at a bunch of correlated time steps. This mimics a possible deployed model where you are retraining your model as you get more data and then predicting just a little ahead.
2. **Why do error metrics decline with a longer training window?**
   The most likely reason for MAPE/RMSE declining as your training set gets long is that you have more data and therefor a more robust estimate of your model parameters. Some change in model performance based on training data length is expected, but if it is very pronounced and your data allows, you can up the minimum number of training samples in your training window. Also make sure you are predicting on the same number of test samples forward from each training window. And as always, be sure to considering overfitting/model complexity in addition to error metrics.
3. **Should I change model order during walk forward validation?**
   The answer is no. You would use one model (like SARIMA(1,1,1)) and run walk forward validation. You would then choose another model (like SARIMA(1,1,2)) and another walk forward validation. This gives an apples to apples comparison of two models across what is hopefully a valid cross section of data to gauge performance. You can think of walk forward validation as an operation that asks how well did my model do? Changing model order mid way through would not answer that question.

Comment: Thank you brent. Point two and three are agreed and is what I have done.  The first question still remains a bit open. Can you a little elaborate on the independence of the samples? Do you have any litertaure by hand regarding this topic? Thank you.

Comment: By saying observations are correlated, I mean for an observed random process $(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)$, $p(x_n | x_n-1, x_n-2, ...) \neq p(x_n)$. In other words, the next observation in time is influenced by what has come before it (standard assumption for times series models). In normal regression modeling, it's assumed there aren't any time conditional probabilities, so observations can be split into train and test without worrying about when in time they occurred. Forward validation accounts for this correlation by splitting train and test time sequentially. I have no literature at hand though

Comment: Yes makes totally sense. But I do not see really the benefit doing the corss validation. The model is optimised based on AIC. What extra conclsuion do i draw from eh cross validation?

Comment: It gives more confidence AIC is correctly estimated. If you only did one train/test split, you might get lucky and have a favorable AIC by chance. Intuitively, If you repeat the process of measuring AIC over multiple train/test splits and it still looks good, you have more confidence in your model.